# Add pagination to a template loaded by query variable

Tags: url-rewriting, templates, pagination, query-variable

I have set a query_var,called men, which loads a custom template displaying men's clothes. The rewrite rule is as follows:

```
add_rewrite_rule('collection/men/?$','index.php?post_type=collection&men=yes','top');
```

and the template redirect code is this:

```
if(get_query_var('men') && is_post_type_archive(array('collection'))){
    add_filter('template_include',function(){
        return get_template_directory().'/clothes-men.php';
    });
}
```

The code works, rewrite working as expected ie. localhost/sample-site/collection/men loads the template. The problem comes when I add standard pagination code, clicking 'Next' results in a 404 error. The link generating the 404 error is localhost/sample-site/collection/men/page/2.

I highly suspect that I need to add a rewrite to make pagination work in this custom template loaded by a query_var but I am a bit mixed up in how to go about it.

What rewrite rule (or any other code) will I need to include in order for pagination to work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of digging over the weekend, I found the solution and indeed, it is a rewrite rule with the paged variable added

```
add_rewrite_rule('collection/men/page/([^/]+)/?$','index.php?post_type=collection&men=yes&paged=$matches[1]','top');
```

Pagination now works in the custom template loaded by query variable. i.e. localhost/sample-site/collection/men/page/2 loads the next page instead of a 404 error